# jQuery .val() returns commas separated values as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to subtract 2 columns and get the value in 3rd column. I have the following code which works as long as there's no comma separated values used in the input box.

```js
const sum = $inputs => $inputs.get().reduce((a, el) => a + (parseInt(el.value, 10) || 0), 0);

function calcTableBox() {
  const $table = $('#TableBox');
  const $row = $table.find('> div');

  $row.each(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    const limiter = parseInt($this.find('.limiter').val(), 10); // parseInt at radix decimal
    const used    = parseInt($this.find('.used').val(), 10);
    const remaining = limiter - used;
    if (!isNaN(remaining)) $this.find('.remaining').val( remaining );
  });

  $table.find('.totallimiter').val(sum($table.find('.limiter')));
  $table.find('.totalused').val(sum($table.find('.used')));
  $table.find('.totalrem').val(sum($table.find('.remaining')));
}

jQuery($ => { // DOM ready

  $(".limiter, .used").on("input", calcTableBox);
  calcTableBox(); // Init

});


function addComma(values) {
    var v = values.value && parseFloat(values.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
    values.value = v.toLocaleString("en-US");
}
```

```css
.TableBox {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 6px;
}

.TableBox input[type=text] {
  max-width: 80px;
}

.TableBox>div {
  display: table-row;
  border-spacing: 5px
}

.TableBox>div>div {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 4px;
}

[readonly] {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="TableBox" class="TableBox" style="width: 100%;">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Limiter</div>
    <div>Used</div>
    <div>Remaining</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="limiter" value="32"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="used" value="23"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="remaining" readonly></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="limiter" value=""  onkeyup="addComma(this);"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="used" value=""  onkeyup="addComma(this);"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="remaining" readonly></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="limiter" value="5"  onkeyup="addComma(this);"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="used" value="3"  onkeyup="addComma(this);"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="remaining" readonly></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="limiter" value=""  onkeyup="addComma(this);"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="used" value=""  onkeyup="addComma(this);"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="remaining" readonly></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Total Cycles: </div>
    <div><input type="text" class="totallimiter" readonly></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="totalused" readonly></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="totalrem" readonly></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Here, the first row works fine as i haven't added any commas to the values. However, in all the other rows i am adding commas. Since the value is a string i am removing commas and doing a parseInt on it for calculation.

```
function calcTableBox() {
  const $table = $('#TableBox');
  const $row = $table.find('> div');

  $row.each(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
   // const limiter = parseInt($this.find('.limiter').val(), 10); // parseInt at radix decimal

    const limiter = $this.find('.limiter').val();
      limiter = limiter.replace(/,/g, "");      
      limiter = parseInt(limiter);

   // const used    = parseInt($this.find('.used').val(), 10);
    const used = jQuerythis.find(".used").val();    
      used = used.replace(/,/g, "");    
      used = parseInt(used);

    const remaining = limiter - used;
    if (!isNaN(remaining)) $this.find('.remaining').val( remaining );
  });

  $table.find('.totallimiter').val(sum($table.find('.limiter')));
  $table.find('.totalused').val(sum($table.find('.used')));
  $table.find('.totalrem').val(sum($table.find('.remaining')));
}
```

The issue is that when i add commas it returns NaN for my values. I read posts  on this and it just asks me set the id of the box and use that to get the values which i am already doing. Any help is appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: Is the function named `addCommas()` or `insertCommas()`? `length` is also a property, remove the trailing `()`

Comment: You don't have any other elements with the `limiter` class do you? Also, isn't `length` a property rather than a function?

Comment: could you add HTML file here?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have tried it through different ways. jQuery seems to return empty values if there's a commas there. I have tried getting values which was converted using .toLocaleString() and it returns undefined there as well.

Comment: @IvanSmyrnov I updated my codes as to what i am trying to do here.

Comment: `const limiter` <-- so you declare it as a `const`, BUT you set the value again and again. `limiter = limiter......` That is not how `const` works. You need to use `let`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? I bet you are. If you follow those error messages to the source of the error, you may discover the answer yourself. There are quite a few issues, from "`length` isn't a function" to "you can't re-assign a value to a const".

Comment: @epascarello I tried to reassign the values using let and var both.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica yes the error says the value is undefined. i tried suing let and var both. Also, tried assigning it to a new var. And i am not using length anymore.

Comment: Which line? Are you getting `undefined` for your `limiter` or `used` value? In that case, `limiter.replace` will fail.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica Reassigning both the values  gives undefined. I tried  const limiter = $this.find('.limiter').val();
const limiter1 = limiter.replace(/,/g, ''); Also tried using let and var.

Comment: You are iterating over your header row, which doesn't have any inputs, and returns `undefined` for `val()`. You then try to treat those `undefined` values as strings, which causes an error. You need to skip the logic if you get `undefined` by just calling `return` early... `if ($this.find('.limiter').length === 0) return;`, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up the comments...

You have several simultaneous issues which are conspiring to torpedo your code. You need to pay attention to error messages and [learn how to follow the console to the source code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) to understand why your code is breaking, but here's what's obvious so far:

1. You were accessing properties as if they were functions (`.length()`) (*You have since edited this out of your question, but it was in the original post*)
2. You were re-assigning values to `const` variables, which is not allowed.
3. You were iterating over the header row, which returned `undefined` for `.val()` since `.find(".limiter")` returned no elements, which caused `limiter.replace` to throw an error since `undefined` values do not have a `.replace` function.
4. This might just be a typo, but your `jQuerythis` variable is not defined. I believe that you meant `$this`, but you'll need to fix that before your code will work.

For the third error in my list, you should be able to solve it with a simple check to make sure you actually have string values. If you don't you can skip the row:

```js
  $row.each(function() {
    const $this = $(this),
        $limiter = $this.find('.limiter'),
        $used = $this.find(".used");
    // Don't process this row if the limiter or used elements are missing:
    if ($limiter.length === 0 || $used.length === 0) return;

    // You might want to add additional checks to make sure that
    // $limiter.val() returns a string, but I assume from your
    // HTML that it is safe to assume a string so long as the
    // element was found.
    const limiterValue = $limiter.val().replace(/,/g, "");
      limiterInt = parseInt(limiterValue);

    const usedValue = $used.val().replace(/,/g, "");
      usedInt = parseInt(usedValue);

    // If either limiterInt or usedInt are NaN, then skip this row.
    // The numbers are invalid.
    // Or maybe you'll want to handle it a different way... that's
    // up to you.
    if (isNan(limiterInt) || isNan(usedInt)) return;

    const remaining = limiterInt - usedInt;
    $this.find('.remaining').val( remaining );
  });
```

Comment: Do you mind posting a solution? Looking at your comments i haven't used length() anywhere. Not sure if you looked at my actual post there which has been updated. Second, i tried solving it without using const and that didn't work. Third, the values are there but for some reason doing a replace doesn't work which is what i am trying to figure out here. Removing the replace part works totally fine for me. My issue is trying to get the values after doing the replace. I would love for you to have a solution to this however because i am stuck. Thank you.

Comment: @ace23 - Your comment suggests that you've tried individual solutions but you don't understand why they didn't work. The problem is that you have more than one error, so you can't get your code working with just one fix. You must fix all of the issues.